# Contenteditable <div>: Cursor starts before the placeholder

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm making a contenteditable div to grab the user input.I want to make the placeholder text starts exactly where the cursor is, however  The demo shows that the placeholder text start 2 characters(white space) behind the cursor. Any idea how to fix it?

```
<div id="comment_box2" contenteditable="true" autofocus="autofocus" autocomplete="off" spellcheck="false" placeholder="this text starts after the cursor"></div>

<style>
/*[contenteditable=true]:empty:before{
  content: attr(placeholder);
  display: block;  For Firefox 
 }*/

#comment_box2{
  background-color: white;

  /*position:relative;*/
  border: 1px solid blue;
  /*height:60px;*/
  width: 500px;
  padding: 10px;
  color:black;
  border-radius:3px;
  text-indent: 10px;
  font-size:18px;

  /*border-color:yellow;*/
}
#comment_box2:focus{
  outline-style:solid;
  outline-color:blue;
  outline-width:0px;
}
</style>




<script type="text/javascript">
    window.onload = function() {
        document.getElementById("comment_box2").focus();
    };
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove: `text-indent: 10px;`

http://jsfiddle.net/cty5cxg7/

Tested in Firefox and Chrome, works fine.